# How can I refrence something between two activities?

Tags: android

So I am making this app and I want this settings page kind of thing where the user can choose if they want the sound on or off how do I reference the playsound method in the second activity?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention settings I assume you use SharedPreferences -if not please do as it is the stander way to implement [settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)-, in this case, it is so easy to so:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean key = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("playsound", false);
```

Comment: where do i write that?

Comment: in onCreate method see MrOrhan.

Answer (score 0):

I used a switch 'button' in my code to solve the same problem like u. here is an example

```
SharedPreferences pref;    
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 MediaPlayer backgroundmusik;
 Switch mute;
 View dummysetting;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checksound_layout);
        //SHARED PREFERENCES
        pref = getSharedPreferences("your_label",MODE_PRIVATE);//label to find in Manifest
        editor = pref.edit();

 backgroundmusik = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dingdong);
        dummysetting = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.setmute_layout,null); //you need that dummy, when u want to check ur button when u are on a different layout other way you get nullpointer.
        mute=(Switch)dummysetting.findViewById(R.id.mute);
        mute.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("Musik", true));//set true or false, its the 'status' when start for the first time after u install app.
        if (mute.isChecked())
        {
            backgroundmusik = MediaPlayer.create(Hauptmenue.this,R.raw.dingdong);
            backgroundmusik.setLooping(true);
            backgroundmusik.start();
        }
}//close oncreat
```

now you can set on an another place in the same activity the mute button like:

```
     setContentView(dummysetting);

        mute.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    backgroundmusik = MediaPlayer.create(MAinactivity.this,R.raw.dingdong);
                    backgroundmusik.setLooping(true);
                    backgroundmusik.start();

                    editor.putBoolean("Musik", true);
                    editor.commit();//safe the edit
                }else
                {
                    backgroundmusik.stop();
                    editor.putBoolean("Musik", false);
                    editor.commit();//safe the edit
                }
            }
        });
}//close main.
```

That was just an example. i comy paste some codes from my code. If doesnt work you can ask again.
AND sharedpreferences can u use from every activity, when u declare and call them in the activity. Need just:

```
 SharedPreferences pref;    
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

then in oncreat

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("your_label",MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
```

and then when u safe as

```
editor.putBoolean("**Musik**", true);
editor.commit();//safe the edit
```

u have to ask for "Musik" again like:

`pref.getBoolean("Musik", true)`

to read.